# Replace part of list by applying operation to it

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I want to replace, say, `list[[i]]` by `f@list[[i]]`. I can use `ReplacePart` as below, but I would like a more elegant way of doing it.

```
list = ReplacePart[list, i -> f@list[[i]]];

list = operateOnPart[list, i, f];
```

Comment: Have you seen `MapAt`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Now I have, thanks!